# How to Hide Help text in Output/Input Feilds?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component

[image]

How do we hide help text in VF pages? Specially in out/input Fields. Any idea, Thanks

Comment: Please upvote an answer and mark it as the solution if your question has been successfully answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the helptext is rendered in as part of the pageBlockSectionItem's Label, you can get around it by manually declaring the section item and label, like so:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Incident_Email__c.fields.Subject__c.Label}"/>
    <apex:inputField id="subjectField" value="{!record.Subject__c}"  />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

and if you wanted to provide alternate helptext (or helptext for a random input that *isn't* tied to an sObject field), you can use the `helptext` attribute of the apex:pageBlockSectionItem

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on your object definition.

If you define the field with some help description, it will be shown. Otherwise, it will not appear.

Look at these examples

[image]

Where

Text with Help is:

[image]

And Parent_Account is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is  I only need hide some of them. Not all of them.

Comment: This answer provides good context info for newbies, but does not address the question...